# How to Gracefully Close a Socket from the Server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, network-programming

On the server side, I'm trying to gracefully close a connected socket.  I know the proper sequence of events on the Socket should be:

1. socket Shutdown with the SocketShutdown.Send option
2. loop/wait until a socket Receive returns with 0 bytes
3. socket Close

I have a few questions:

1. what if Socket.Receive never returns (with 0 bytes)?  will we be stuck trying to close the socket forever?
2. whenever i call Close on the server, the Client always receives "an existing connection was forcibly closed by a remote host" exception on their end.  how can i have the client notified of this close "gracefully"?
3. on the server, if I'm using Async Begin/EndReceive calls, whenever I call Close on the socket, it ALWAYS results in an ObjectDisposedException on the Begin/EndReceive thread.  Is there no way to Close a socket without this exception from occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The TCP protocol guarantees the socket will close eventually unless the peer refuses to allow it to close. In which case, you should wait forever or give up, whatever's appropriate.
2. If you close the socket after receive returns zero, that should not happen. If it is, your code is likely doing something wrong.
3. You can't release a resource while an asynchronous operation is or might be using it. Rather than calling close, call shutdown. Don't call close until you're 100% finished with the resource.

Comment: thanks for your reply!  related to #1 and #2: what causes the server side to receive bytes == 0?  as in, after the server calls Shutdown, what does the client see and what does the client need to do to ensure the server gets the appropriate disconnection event (i.e. receive bytes == 0)?  for #3: there is no way to "break" the socket from the async operation even if you know you're 100% finished w/ the resource.  MSDN instructs to call Close to exit the async loop but in my experience, this has always caused ObjectDisposedException to occur.

Comment: The client does the same thing, shutting down the socket and receiving until it gets a zero. There is no real distinction between the ends of a TCP connection once it's established. The way to break the async operation is to shutdown the underlying connection. The async operation should then complete.

Comment: how/when does the Client know to call Shutdown (if it was the server that initiated the Shutdown)?

Comment: i've been doing some testing of my own and i can't seem to ever get the server side to receive zero bytes if the shutdown is initiated by the server.  if the server initiates the shutdown, the client will receive zero bytes, but if the client doesn't call shutdown, the server never receives 0 bytes in return.  are you saying that the server should expect the client to call shutdown after receiving zero bytes???

Comment: when the server calls shutdown, the client will eventually receive 0 bytes.  at this point, the client can call shutdown then close (or just close, which will automatically call shutdown) which will cause the server to receive 0 bytes.  then the server can call Close without generating any exceptions (even in the async call as you had said).  everything you said was correct.. i just had to think it through to understand the entire picture.  thanks!!